# How do I check whether there is amount of money in monero wallet using JSON RPC?

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, monero

I'm trying to implement Monero trading on my website. Monero is anonymous and I struggle to see whether there is Monero on user's address.

I tried to figure out how Monero encryption works and read this [Article](https://hackernoon.com/blockchain-privacy-enhancing-technology-series-stealth-address-i-c8a3eb4e4e43?fbclid=IwAR21hBtfLXUUfQ8KXJFGTj13vn5n2twrow265bwk2hXCvVyJkq_hMoD2v94). In **Dual-Key Stealth Address Protocol (DKSAP)** sender generates ephemeral public and private keys. Can it help?
I tried to get transaction information using $curl and got this :

> "as_json": "{\n  \"version\": 2, \n  \"unlock_time\": 0, \n  \"vin\": [ {\n      \"key\": {\n        \"amount\": 0, \n        \"key_offsets\": [ 9571731, 2381465, 486794, 83759, 248178, 7082, 3799, 1279, 1530, 2466, 272\n        ], \n        \"k_image\": \"8bf34f1daad7d6fcdfe6b81e0785746c95342add3cac4da90e2d3f4319c8332d\"\n      }\n    }\n  ], \n  \"vout\": [ {\n      \"amount\": 0, \n      \"target\": {\n        \"key\": \"20bbbab6ef3b52227097e51d984a5657babf4a5022fae9490a098de4fec01886\"\n      }\n    }, {\n      \"amount\": 0, \n      \"target\": {\n        \"key\": \"9b5cb9be20bf9d10916360f022aa98df1bbb884f1d5a6e4939915a4397860e13\"\n      }\n    }\n  ], \n  \"extra\": [ 2, 9, 1, 216, 175, 101, 25, 135, 253, 50, 62, 1, 175, 47, 75, 52, 87, 228, 98, 175, 48, 238, 202, 36, 10, 224, 94, 157, 209, 22, 126, 153, 244, 211, 134, 217, 169, 102, 172, 46, 60, 237, 153, 165\n  ], \n  \"rct_signatures\": {\n    \"type\": 4, \n    \"txnFee\": 26660000, \n    \"ecdhInfo\": [ {\n        \"amount\": \"3e29fac67d121705\"\n      }, {\n        \"amount\": \"fdc4b4a1366821c8\"\n      }], \n    \"outPk\": [ \"c01d729681ed8fa48c09509ce0fa9cae16b3d67f03f8653ba4dea895d62547b2\", \"e72ef77998ead493c57268dfc9c72449585c68b6d595dc595aef515de9466ab8\"]\n  }, \n  \"rctsig_prunable\": {\n    \"nbp\": 1, \n    \"bp\": [ {\n        \"A\": \"67631e5097a3da94279e8e0394c61bea528e19078f10dd2d823151d8d018fbc6\", \n        \"S\": \"b595bda7d3192ca30c10849318669d88dc3940fe68b1573d217441826ddb06ad\", \n        \"T1\": \"8b2725a716cbe8b91b90326e5bcae42590a67f0dbff2cca37a59fb519976ccda\", \n        \"T2\": \"cdc3e82476e65452e4f7eea69f725315cb21a3f793143e25dfa78df1ab7ddee9\", \n        \"taux\": \"8bb54ad9d00a910baed462d4a96f08b61f51e0ea7dd653562ceebad6b6459809\", \n        \"mu\": \"c8418187e0ec2cbb54d154a8b187c94fe97c9c91c6b3e53440680788f7dcb605\", \n        \"L\": [ \"144d9dc6fe20c3ead20f40e8ed635edd580bda250037859cf583eb12d085ec9b\", \"c1d26ca904adddd34def680d2128c81123c73da44ecdfe686c3ce149983788c6\", \"0e1bed05a3c2127285661259f4db243639ac859fd101ef62abf85019aa339a4a\", \"f7881aed9a7f4bd1254b983fc936bd0115fed948311d38224f6fdc3218cdc619\", \"e25f7167bc68beefae718c4f1c6d2e29a358e4faad55e572802c44eb03f2b2bd\", \"115d17464c10684cb10062fbca08b07d8e555402a1e509c87f14acb7cef45f6f\", \"36464c3e8803752472fa73964ceb03644f65a460fd4404a37428d50e0bd8067e\"\n        ], \n        \"R\": [ \"0c907df3524ed279b32a50a3db6709390f3c65d3ef9df52d6dfb0b30f75a8ae4\", \"d12967dac1a55aa66385066f888f3c26a1c2215c17ceb5848b26e483e335756d\", \"aff64e06052a950fec0d8127fd1b037e0f58b4b5d2f635bb04150078212ba1cc\", \"b9b8174f4c45a6ef4328dbde83e8ca3a5a51bcff5f249d6cfda93515c59740f4\", \"6d11e48e80770152d1739a168bfa52202c077871d5365a0e95345b64fb91c840\", \"37cc090c34e5da18945ba2adc79bad14100cff4d45710c264c12bc387b22984a\", \"96ed15063af004a3f12715109b2b52897f0f80a5d6cdd080a08cc392a68a41a1\"\n        ], \n        \"a\": \"7a2e8135df02c4596c3fd4ce1aec79ec504677e445126d33b07f947e4217050e\", \n        \"b\": \"002963189fa7f334634cfe36a510b96ab48bb30359abaaaf8602713f0bbc4906\", \n        \"t\": \"12b16a421bb9dd9a6c82c0c44c3d8e574199212a37a2026bed4263c452e34c07\"\n      }\n    ], \n    \"MGs\": [ {\n        \"ss\": [ [ \"6e19bb620cb1a94b1d028f124c1a356205a84607124ed03779cb98b39c91fb02\", \"98bc4a1751db1f3c6ef1129fd10ceb9a948aa58c7b39d99b057ddd00acb7d601\"], [ \"89b11d508b9298c59b9f4e06748a8a9f57fa9b9e0eae25abec82268ba1bb4f03\", \"d8d0f303677a9ea4f75608e4f244986efe9a4e6a832bc6c90dd5a7e583de0602\"], [ \"d09926caf2d0830b735910248a6d4d279879a89413efbc4373ac46de1be09f0d\", \"7e925df86d4856b06760958137ae062a8dccb3f4ad2a1ffa108c58f8e0b9180a\"], [ \"3dacddb70d16d7889da79cd3920dfd3e86f314bfaa7fb37089115bb3ce66e901\", \"698a021c321251dfdf99baaa6d45e7aca6372c496f6b275554afd01114b44a0e\"], [ \"aaa509c06d1144d51d0c2dccdc22e54750616b371cd2f8d0e2a64aa1f51a9d03\", \"5b890a4e0558ebb5fff35782dd24d4239d16f4dbf4a2cf02302f944392c16f0d\"], [ \"80120d472952b23b445aaf8d141b6545fb2f9584e3f9ada6208e137a1d3a130c\", \"ac23443b467875e22672c41954732af4717a1200c10fe3b704623112981b8b02\"], [ \"0afe38237c3daece0b8c73a771cd6e45e17262b684f9632b03f47fdf1d025006\", \"9cfeeb48e9988415425ed9289c4d0cf5c9d0f92ab3b4eae55f92a1f893399106\"], [ \"27d8c00de277b588d984d159678e8b3da60406d2d8e172305e35b08d4e9bf10a\", \"ce83f2b2831d6104c278949366844fca0089c9101ec3a92bb338d4729079790b\"], [ \"77a6b568a67bcd074196869b030434c85e2d5c771f6db219f01541d2c1e24509\", \"0abb1e007fa334bf808f9a9a07c69be4cf30068bfe226735c450a3c0a504370c\"], [ \"c3586335c3005311165793019f6ec946f84a25d9e06ed540ff611175abf19a0a\", \"c26e5192e6ea5bbd3819671b09b6c66370f8dd0bb1624ffc19aaaf35eb82fe0f\"], [ \"39d83cbc0dca88627cb472537ea8fad857bdc8f55f6d0f890085981d40098803\", \"e0ef2ca4f401cda0bfdc1e6b2f7380f542ed0aa9359829e98ee27d23d37c5d09\"]], \n        \"cc\": \"c6e728e84694d8ad880b112b2ff034cb82bab4951d100dd76587ed289cf95206\"\n      }], \n    \"pseudoOuts\": [ \"51cbc62920f0a65e02af1a726ef17811de8f4048a312088dfd842576837c776e\"]\n  }\n}",

```
"block_height": 1947420,

"block_timestamp": 1571406596,

"double_spend_seen": false,

"in_pool": false,

"output_indices": [12788686,12788687],

"prunable_as_hex": "",

"prunable_hash": "e11b75587bd668216491caaca2dfd42d3b8a29e1486022c821d82d17b20777d7",

"pruned_as_hex": "",

"tx_hash": "8759348a3c55ada4d378e439c44d7e833732a27c06c6df5122a595874ea7c9c4"
```

}],

Answer (score 1):

Just run this curl with username and password.

curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18082/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_balance","params":{"account_index":0,"address_indices":[0,1]}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

Through this, you can check the balance of Monero